# Multiple alignments in align environment

Tags: align

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&u = \frac{1}{\theta_{2,3}} \left [ -z_1 - \left ( c_2 + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right )z_2 - \theta_{2,1}\sin(x_1) - \hat{\theta}_{2,2}x_2 + \dot{\alpha}_1 \right ] \\ 
&\dot{\xi}_{2,2} = - \frac{\partial \beta_2}{\partial x_2}\left [ \theta_{2,1}\sin(x_1)+\left ( \xi_{2,2}  + \beta_2(x_2) \right ) x_2 + \theta_{2,3}u \right ]  \\
&\hat{\theta}_{2,2} = \xi_{2,2} + \beta_2(x_2) \\
&\beta_2 =  \frac{\gamma}{2}x_2^2 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

That is, next to the left alignment, I want to align the equal signs of equations (2) to (4).

Comment: `align` always aligns with the left-hand side aligned to the right before the sign of relation.  you'd be better off using `alignat`, for which you need to explicitly indicate where you want spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `two` alignment points for the last three equations, you can use the `alignat` environment, combined with `\mathrlap` command, defined in `mathtools (which loads`amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
&u \mathrlap{{}=\frac{1}{\theta_{2,3}} \left [ -z_1 - \left ( c_2 + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right )z_2 - \theta_{2,1}\sin(x_1) - \hat{\theta}_{2,2}x_2 + \dot{\alpha}_1 \right ]} \\
&\dot{\xi}_{2,2} &&= - \frac{\partial \beta_2}{\partial x_2}\left [ \theta_{2,1}\sin(x_1)+\left ( \xi_{2,2}  + \beta_2(x_2) \right ) x_2 + \theta_{2,3}u \right ]  \\
 & \hat{\theta}_{2,2} & &= \xi_{2,2} + \beta_2(x_2) \\
&\beta_2 &&= \frac{\gamma}{2}x_2^2
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `\begin{alignat}{3}`? It is not enough with `\begin{alignat}{2}`?

Comment: I forgot to go back to 2. I always do that to have the possibility to add an ampersand or two if required on testing. I'll reset the correct value at once.You're right, it might be confusing.