# Align-environment: Align on the left side

Tags: align

Why doesn't the following code align the two equations in the middle?
It does only if I remove the alignment on the left.

```
\begin{align*}
    &ABC  &= ABC - AB\\
    &ABCD &= ABC - ABCDEFG
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! An `align` environment is basically a sequence of `rl` column pairs, with a wide space between pairs.

Comment: here's another question that addresses this problem: [Multiple alignments in align environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195167/579).  there are probably others.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An `align` or `align*` environment is a set of `rl` column pairs, with a wide space between each pair.

You want to use `alignat`, which does the same, but adds no space between pairs of columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&ABC  &&= ABC - AB\\
&ABCD &&= ABC - ABCDEFG
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\begin{alignat*}{2}` you allocate four columns, in the form `rlrl`, so you want `&` to get into the `l` column and `&&` to get in the next `l` column; note that cells in `l` columns have an automatic `{}` inserted so as to give correct spacing for the relation or operation symbols.