# Aligning linear program with numbers

Tags: equations, alignat

How can I fit my linear program to my sheet but still have numbers aligned on the right?

```
\documentclass{article}

% page layout
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=50mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}

% fancy math
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\textbf{Minimize} \\
&z =\sum\limits_{i \in I}\sum\limits_{t \in W_i^{work}} c^{period} * x_{i,t}^{work} + \sum\limits_{i \in I} c^{over} * o_i + \sum\limits_{i \in I} c^{staff} * v_i^{staff} + \sum\limits_{d \in D} c^{device} * v_d^{device} \\
&\textbf{subject to}  \\
&\sum\limits_{i \in I_{q':q'=q}} (( \sum\limits{r=t}^{t+W_z^{demand}} x_{i,r}^{work} - y_{i,t}^{break} ) * v_i^{staff}) \geq b_{q,t,z}^{staff} && \forall q \in Q,t \in T, z \in Z \\
&H^{break} * \sum\limits{t \in W_i^{shift}} y_{i,t}^{shift} = \sum\limits{t \in W_i^{break}} y_{i,t}^{break} && \forall i \in I \\
&D_i^{min} \leq \sum\limits{t \in T} y_{i,t}^{shift} \leq D_i^{max} && \forall i \in I
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

That's what I have so far:

[image: lp solution]

Maybe splitting some formulas is a solution?
How tiny can I make the font till it is no longer readable?

I followed [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200502/align-environment-align-on-the-left-side) using `alignat`, sadly there is no numbering and it is much smaller.

**Edit #1:**
`\quad` helped a lot, but one line is missing.

[image]

Comment: You need to replace the three instances of `&&` with `\quad`.

Comment: Besides all, you need vector notation. Summations are simply confusing and hard to read.

Comment: Thanks I updated my question, sadly still one is misfits (see edit 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the following

- Replace the three instances of `&&` before `\forall` with `\quad`. Optionally, since there's now only one alignment point left, replace `{alignat}{2}` with `align`.
- Add `\notag` instructions to the two lines that contain just text ("minimize", "subject to")
- Force all words in superscript position to be typeset in text-upright instead of math-italic mode. I would do this even if it didn't help make the first equation fit within the text block (which it does, happily). If you strongly prefer text-italics over text-upright mode for the words in the superscript positions, replace `\textnormal` in the definition of the `\tn` macro with `\textit`.
- Enlarge the parentheses in the first condition line using `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`. To snug up the first and second summation symbols in that line, insert `\!\!\!` -- three negative thinspaces.
- To force the limits of summation of the two summation expressions in the first math row to be set at the same depth, replace `{i \in I}` with `{i \in I^{\mathstrut}}`. A `\mathstrut` is an invisible object with the height and depth of a parenthesis (`(`).
- Finally, I would delete all `\limits` directives, as they are redundant and just provide clutter. The material in `align` and `alignat` environments is typeset in `\displaystyle` by default, meaning that all summation signs will be set in "large" form and all limits of summation will be set below (and, if present, above) the summation symbols rather than side-set on the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=50mm,right=20mm,
            top=20mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\newcommand\tn[1]{\textnormal{#1}} % shortcut macro
\usepackage{amsmath}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\textbf{Minimize} \notag \\
&z =\sum_{i \in I^{\mathstrut}}\sum_{t \in W_i^{\tn{work}}} c^{\tn{period}} * x_{i,t}^{\tn{work}} + \sum_{i \in I} c^{\tn{over}} * o_i + \sum_{i \in I} c^{\tn{staff}} * v_i^{\tn{staff}} + \sum_{d \in D} c^{\tn{device}} * v_d^{\tn{device}} \\
&\textbf{subject to} \notag \\
&\sum_{i \in I_{q':q'=q}} \!\!\! \Bigl(\Bigl( \sum{r=t}^{t+W_z^{\tn{demand}}} x_{i,r}^{\tn{work}} - y_{i,t}^{\tn{break}} \Bigr) * v_i^{\tn{staff}}\Bigr) \geq b_{q,t,z}^{\tn{staff}} \quad \forall q \in Q,t \in T, z \in Z \\
&H^{\tn{break}} * \sum{t \in W_i^{\tn{shift}}} y_{i,t}^{\tn{shift}} = \sum{t \in W_i^{\tn{break}}} y_{i,t}^{\tn{break}} \quad \forall i \in I \\
&D_i^{\tn{min}} \leq \sum{t \in T} y_{i,t}^{\tn{shift}} \leq D_i^{\tn{max}} \quad \forall i \in I
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. One further question. Can I also change the setting to textit to textnormal all over my document?

Comment: @lony - Sure. In fact, I'd make an effort to use the `\tn` macro for all word-like terms that occur in a math context. In the example you've given the terms only occur in superscript positions, but I could well imagine that they can appear elsewhere too. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, they could. Is it possible to avoid the macro and just "set" the font right?

Comment: @lony - Not sure what you mean by "setting the font right". Are you expecting TeX to somehow "know" if a superscript term is supposed to be set in upright roman letters? If the only words that can arise in a math context are period, over, staff, work, break, demand, device, and shift, you could define macros such as `\def\period{{\tn{period}}` and then use `\period` whenever the term occurs in math mode. (The macros `\min` and `\max` are already pre-defined, so don't re-define  them.)

Comment: I mean if I can set a "setting in TeX" to always use your macros font and avoid adding it to all the text formulas inside my hole document?